# Error ao mudar o tipo de uma coluna de smalldatetime para int

Tags: sql-server, conversão-de-tipo

Estou tentando mudar o tipo de uma coluna da minha tabela, que esta vazia, de smalldatetime para inteiro.

Error:

> A conversão implícita do tipo de dados de smalldatetime para int não é
>   permitida. Para executar a consulta, use a função CONVERT.

Estou tentando desta forma :

```
ALTER TABLE Table_Name
ALTER COLUMN Column_Name INT NOT NULL
```

OBS: Quando eu tento converter para outro tipo, exemplo: VARCHAR(20), funciona.

O que estou fazendo de errado ?

Comment: se tiver duvida de como converter, diga o formato que a data vai ter como inteiro e posso ajudar com o sql

Comment: @Ricardo Pontual a data vai estar no formato de Unix TimeStamp. Estou convertendo tudo para Varchar e depois para inteiro, se existir alguma forma de fazer esta conversão de forma mais rápida agradeço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Porque não é possível converter um tipo `smalldatetime` para `int`. Imagine dizer ao SQL "converta 01/01/2019 para um número inteiro", como ser isso? Como supostamente ele deveria converter? Dividir 1 por 1 e depois por 2019? Ele não sabe exatamente o que fazer nessa conversão.

Para `varchar` funciona porque é um texto, então é possível armazenar os dados como estão, com tudo que houver além de números (barras, dois-pontos, etc).

O que pode ser feito é, alterar para `varchar`, fazer um `update` que formate corretamente somente com números, e em seguida alterar novamente para `int`

Supondo que sua tabela se chame "Teste" e a coluna `smaldatetime` se chame "campo", poderia fazer assim:

- Criar um nova coluna do tipo int
- Fazer o update dessa coluna convertendo a data (usei a function `datediff` me baseando nessa outra pergunta: [convert smalldatetime to unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307304/how-do-i-convert-an-sql-server-smalldatetime-to-a-unix-timestamp)
- Remover a coluna antiga
- Renomear a nova para "campo":

.

```
alter table teste
  add campo_int int;

 update teste
    set campo_int = datediff(ss, '19700101', campo);

alter table teste
 drop column campo;
```

Pode ver um exemplo funcionando aqui: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8afd3/1)

Comment: Funciona desta forma mesmo com a tabela vazia ?

Comment: mesmo estando vazia a tabela não é permitida essa alteração, vai acontecer o mesmo erro